# What does the letter 'u' mean in /dev/urandom?

Tags: linux, devices, history, random

I understand that reads to `/dev/random` may block, while reading `/dev/urandom` is guaranteed not to block.

Where does the letter `u` come into this? What does it signify?

Userspace? Unblocking? Micro?

*Update:*

Based on the initial wording of the question, there has been some debate over the usefulness of `/dev/random` vs `/dev/urandom`. The link [Myths about /dev/urandom](http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/) has been posted three times below, and is summarised in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/324210/143394) to the question [When to use /dev/random vs /dev/urandom](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/324209/143394).

Comment: Unblocking, as opposed to `/dev/random` which is blocking.

Comment: Chapter and verse?

Comment: The idea that `/dev/random` was somehow better than `/dev/urandom` is now long obsolete and for the vast majority of use cases, `/dev/urandom` [is now preferred](http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/).

Comment: @SatoKatsura Source? Tom's answer contradicts your answer.

Comment: Here is a link to site with details to backup @DavidSchwartz 's comment. http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/

Comment: @Walter The "is now preferred" part in David's comment is a link to that page. :)

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC That's ok, I _can_ stand other people disagreeing with me. :) IIRC `/dev/urandom` did exist on commercial systems before Linux, and the main difference from `/dev/random` was blocking behavior, but I don't have a reference to point you to.  If you believe a comment in a patch from 1995 is the proper explanation, go with that.  Maybe it _is_ the proper explanation for Linux.  You guys could also just ask T. Ts'o (the author of the patch).

Comment: @SatoKatsura [Hitchen's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitchens%27s_razor): can you provide some evidence for you assertion rather than asking us to contact someone extremely in-demand to disprove it? Note, I did try to find this evidence myself (see comments in my answer).

Comment: From my comment above: "I don't have a reference to point you to" (which is why I didn't post it as an answer). As for Hitchen's razor, whatever that might be: I wasn't asking you to do anything to prove or disprove my claim. I was just pointing out there _is_ a way to get a definitive answer to your question, rather than speculate on [unix.se]. Not sure why you're assuming contacting Theodore Ts'o would be such a huge endeavor. Still, please _do_ ignore me on both counts if that makes you feel better.

Comment: @SatoKatsura "Not sure why you're assuming contacting Theodore Ts'o would be such a huge endeavor" agreed, especially since he's a [user on this site](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/52238/theodore-tso) already!

Comment: @SatoKatsura Hitchen's razor is explained in Wikipedia link I gave, but in summary: `the burden of proof regarding the truthfulness of a claim lies with the one who makes the claim; if this burden is not met, the claim is unfounded and its opponents need not argue further in order to dismiss it.` I admit you may be right though! :)  Also note that I didn't say that it would be a "huge endevour" - my intent was to say that he is likely a busy guy and currently the burden of proof lies upon you.

Comment: Surely it would have been /dev/nrandom for "non-blocking" rather than unblocking.

Comment: @MrMoose I posted a comment earlier with a few alternative interpretations. Some moderator wisely decided to delete my comment, but I'll (shamelessly) recall two of them here: _useless_, because people in the know claim `/dev/urandom` is weaker than `/dev/random`; and _useful_, because other people in the know claim we should still use `/dev/urandom`. Also, a few other things (f.i. `umount` and `fsck`) were not initially intended to be named that way. So pick carefully. :)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

**Unlimited.**

In Linux, comparing the kernel functions named [`random_read`](http://repo.or.cz/davej-history.git/blob/d0562c8dc:/drivers/char/random.c#l639) and [`random_read_unlimited`](http://repo.or.cz/w/davej-history.git/blob/d0562c8dc:/drivers/char/random.c#l682)
 indicates that the etymology of the letter `u` in `urandom` is`unlimited`.

This is confirmed by [line 114](http://repo.or.cz/davej-history.git/blob/d0562c8dc:/drivers/char/random.c#l114):

> The /dev/urandom device does not have this limit [...]

*Update:*

Regarding which came first for Linux, `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom`, @Stéphane Chazelas gave the [post with the original patch](https://groups.google.com/forum/message/raw?msg=sci.crypt/d2TXVQOXd5U/499jOckdUuwJ) and @StephenKitt showed [they were both introduced simultaneously](http://repo.or.cz/davej-history.git/commitdiff/88d15e9d250c95e23194c29888d5ca4f86e37581#patch18).

Comment: Then why isn't `/dev/random` named `/dev/lrandom`? :)

Comment: Historical. At first only the limited / blocking version existed. And the analogous "non-un-limited" function is called `random_read` :)

Comment: [Wikipedia says unlimited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random#cite_note-5), also citing `random_read_unlimited` function (in fact, even the same commit). If you got this from Wikipedia, please say so.

Comment: I did find one of the links via Wikipedia, but I'm quoting the source directly rather than quoting Wikipedia. I'd consider it analogous to finding something via google, and not quoting google... unless I have something to learn about quoting on StackExchange?

Comment: @TomHale The historical argument for `random` v. `lrandom` doesn't hold all that well since both `random` and `urandom` were introduced [simultaneously](http://repo.or.cz/davej-history.git/commitdiff/88d15e9d250c95e23194c29888d5ca4f86e37581#patch18) in the Linux kernel.

Comment: @TomHale 2007 is the date at which the 1.3.30 kernel was imported into the historical git repository you're referring to, not the date at which the patch was applied to the kernel originally. 1.3.30 was released in 1995, so it predates Solaris 7. (git didn't exist back then.)

Comment: @StephenKitt Thanks for the correction. I deleted the comment you were referring to by accident, but [here is](https://blogs.oracle.com/yenduri/entry/dev_random_in_solaris) the Solaris link I originally posted.

Comment: See also [the patch](https://groups.google.com/forum/message/raw?msg=sci.crypt/d2TXVQOXd5U/499jOckdUuwJ) on usenet sent by the author of the original implementation back in 1995

Comment: @TomHale It's not analogous because some person did the work for finding that reference and adding it to Wikipedia. Not acknowledging that doesn't seem right. I'm sorry, but I'm downvoting this.

Comment: @TomHale instead of telling people to disregard upvotes on your comment, you could delete the comment...

Comment: @StephenKitt, agree, referring to the upvotes wasn't helpful (edited). I'm leaving the comment as-is as I don't want to create another discontinuity and there's some because of the info re `random_read`.

Answer (score 21):

It depends on which "Unix" system you are talking about.

On FreeBSD, /dev/urandom and /dev/random are the same device. The letter u is now a historical legacy that exists for backward compatibility. At startup, they block until enough entropy has been gather and then never block again. See [Myths about urandom](http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/) for details.

In the modern Linux world (starting with kernel 4.8), both devices pull from the same CSPRNG, so the only difference is that some people speculate at the existence of an attack. This attack is like FTL [Faster than Light] travel. Easy to speculate about, rather hard to actually design.

TLDR is just use /dev/urandom.

Comment: From your link, it's interesting to note that `FreeBSD does the right thing: they don't have the distinction between /dev/random and /dev/urandom, both are the same device. At startup /dev/random blocks once until enough starting entropy has been gathered. Then it won't block ever again.`

Answer (score -6):

Uniform.  Random numbers uniformly distributed between 0 and 1.  A flat distribution... as opposed to a peaked distribution like Poisson, or Normal/Gaussian.

Comment: Have any source for that one?

Comment: This is definitely not right- `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` both give the same distribution, and in any real sense it's not uniformly distributed between 0 and 1.

Comment: Sorry... probably based that on another language I have used (R or something)